# Tesseract OCR with OpenCV struggling to detect numbers

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

Hey Im working on a personal project where Im trying to read pictures of this binary wallpaper. I have the OCR working with screen shots of text and pictures of text but then struggle's with the pictures I took of the wallpaper. Here is the code I have so far with the preprocessing.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "basicOCR.h"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void getText(string imPath, string outPath)
{
    char *outText;
    ofstream outputFile(outPath);

    double count, avg, lowest = 100;

    Mat im = cv::imread(imPath);
    if (im.empty())
    {
        cerr << "Error reading image file" << endl;
        return;
    }
    Mat imGray, imDenoised,imThresholded, imInverted;
    fastNlMeansDenoising(im, imDenoised);
    cvtColor(imDenoised, imGray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(imGray, imThresholded, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV | THRESH_OTSU);
    // bitwise_not(imThresholded, imInverted);

    cv::imshow("idk", im);
    waitKey(0);
    cv::imshow("idk", imDenoised);
     waitKey(0);
    cv::imshow("idk", imGray);
    waitKey(0);
    cv::imshow("idk", imThresholded);
    waitKey(0);
    //cv::imshow("idk", imInverted);
   //waitKey(0);



    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();

    if (api->Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_LSTM_ONLY))
    {
        cerr << "Could not initialize tesseract " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    api->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_AUTO);
    api->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "01 ");

    api->SetImage(imThresholded.data, imThresholded.cols, imThresholded.rows, imThresholded.channels(), imThresholded.step);
    api->Recognize(0);
    tesseract::ResultIterator *ri = api->GetIterator();
    tesseract::PageIteratorLevel level = tesseract::RIL_TEXTLINE;
    if (ri != 0)
    {
        do
        {
            const char *word = ri->GetUTF8Text(level);
            float conf = ri->Confidence(level);
            int x1, y1, x2, y2;
            ri->BoundingBox(level, &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);
            
            // outputFile << word << endl;
            outputFile << word << "conft :" <<conf << "box: " << x1 << ", "<< y1 <<", "<< x2 <<", "<< y2<<endl;
            count++;
            avg += conf;
            if (conf < lowest)
            {
                lowest = conf;
            }

            delete[] word;
        } while (ri->Next(level));
    }
    avg = avg / count;
    //cout << "average: " << avg << " lowest: " << lowest << " count: " << count << endl;
    // Destroy used object and release memory
    api->End();
    delete api;
    delete[] outText;

    outputFile.close();

}
```

This is an example of the pictures I start with and them after preprocessing as well as the results it gives.
Image 1:
[image: start][image: after]
Small example of the incomplete output
[image: output]

Image 2:
[image: start]
[image: after]
incomplete/bad output
[image: output]

Testing with good image however(screen shot of text for testing) works well as you can see:
[image: Starting image]
[image: after]

```
01010111011010000110010101110010011001010110000101110011001000000100100100101100001000000101010001101000011011
conft :88.0777box: 12, 12, 2008, 38
11011100110010111000100000010001110010111000100000010000110110110001100101011011010111001101101111011011100010110
conft :84.2204box: 12, 52, 2015, 78
000100000011011110110011000100000011101000110100001100101001000000110001101101111011101010110111001110100011110
conft :88.6689box: 12, 92, 1996, 118
0100100000011000010110111001100100001000000101001101110100011000010111010001100101001000000110000101100110011
conft :90.9737box: 12, 132, 2004, 158
01111011100100110010101110011011000010110100101100100001011000010000001100100011010010110010000101100001000000
conft :90.6547box: 12, 172, 2015, 198
1101111011011100010000001110100011010000110010100100000001100010011010001110100011010000010000001100100011000
conft :80.3054box: 12, 212, 2006, 238
010111100100100000011011110110011000100000010000010111010101100111011101010111001101110100001011000010000000110
conft :90.085box: 12, 252, 2008, 278
00100111000001110000011001100101100001000000110010101111000011001010110001101110101011101000110010100100000011
conft :88.2993box: 12, 292, 2002, 318
011010111100100100000011011000110000101110011011101000010000001110111011010010110110001101100001000000110000101
conft :90.2082box: 12, 332, 2011, 358
1011100110010000100000011101000110010101110011011101000110000101101101011001010110111001110100001000000111011101
conft :89.7693box: 12, 372, 2004, 398
1010000110010101110010011001010110100101101110001000000100100100100000011100110110111101110101011001110110100001
conft :90.4729box: 12, 412, 2009, 438
110100001000000111010001101111001000000111000001110010011011110111011001101001011001000110010100100000011001100
conft :86.2895box: 12, 452, 2013, 478
110111101110010001000000111010001101000011001010010000001100101011100110111010001100001011000100110110001101001
conft :80.1342box: 12, 492, 2006, 518
011100110110100001101101011001010110111001110100001000000110111101100110001000000110000100100000011100110110001
conft :88.2358box: 12, 532, 2006, 558
10110100101100101011011100111010001101001011001100110100101100011001000000110100101101110011100110111010001101001
conft :90.798box: 12, 572, 2007, 598
01110100011101010111010001101001011011110110111000100000011101010111000001101111011011100010000001110100011010000
conft :90.4437box: 12, 612, 2014, 638
11001010010000001000110011011110111001001110100001000000100100001101001011011000110110000100000011100000110110
conft :84.508box: 12, 652, 2015, 678
0011000010110001101100101001011000010000001100001011011100110010000100000011101000110100001100101011100100110
conft :89.6527box: 12, 692, 2001, 718
0101011010010110111000100000011100000111001001101111011101100110100101100100011001010110010000100000011101110110
conft :90.0513box: 12, 732, 2011, 758
100001100001011101000010000001110011011000110110100101100101011011100110001101100101011100110010000001110011011
conft :90.2266box: 12, 772, 1994, 798
010000110111101110101011011000110010000100000011000100110010100100000011101000110000101110101011001110110100001
conft :90.1966box: 12, 812, 2011, 838
11010000100000011010010110111000100000011100110110000101101001011001000010000001101001011011100111001101110100
conft :87.2125box: 12, 852, 1998, 878
0110100101110100011101010111010001101001011011110110111000111011001000000110000101101110011001000010110000100000
conft :90.2893box: 12, 892, 2011, 918
01110111011010000110010101110010011001010110000101110011001011000010000001001001001000000110000101101101001000
conft :90.7194box: 12, 932, 2010, 958
0001101110011011110111011100100000011100110110000101110100011010010111001101100110011010010110010101100100001000
conft :90.5289box: 12, 972, 2000, 998
000111010001101000011000010111010000100000011011010111100100100000011010010110111001110100011001010110111001110
conft :91.2375box: 12, 1012, 2001, 1038
1000110100101101111011011100010000001100001011011100110010000100000011100000111010101110010011100000110111101110
conft :90.6577box: 12, 1052, 2011, 1078
011011001010010000001110100011010000110010101110010011001010110100101101110001000000110110101100001011110010010
conft :90.5476box: 12, 1092, 2007, 1118
0000011000100110010100100000011011010110100101110011011101010110111001100100011001010111001001110011011101000110
conft :89.923box: 12, 1132, 2005, 1158
1111011011110110010000100000011000010111001100100000011010010110111001110100011001010110111001100100011010010110
conft :81.7068box: 12, 1172, 2006, 1198
111001100111001000000111010001101000011000010111010000100000011011100110111100100000011011110111010001101000011
conft :88.5252box: 12, 1212, 2000, 1238
001010111001000100000011100110111010001110101011001000110100101100101011100110010000001101111011100100010000001
conft :89.3194box: 12, 1252, 2006, 1278
110011011000110110100101100101011011100110001101100101011100110010000001110011011010000110111101110101011011000110
conft :79.005box: 12, 1292, 2012, 1318
0100001000000110001001100101001000000111010001100001011101010110011101101000011101000010000001101001011011100
conft :90.8077box: 12, 1332, 2001, 1358
010000001110011011000010110100101100100001000000110100101101110011100110111010001101001011101000111010101110100
conft :90.2748box: 12, 1372, 1996, 1398
0110100101101111011011100010000001110100011010000110000101101110001000000111010001101000011011110111001101100101
conft :90.4792box: 12, 1412, 2004, 1438
001000000110110101100101011011100111010001101001011011110110111001100101011001000010000001101001011011100010000
conft :90.9313box: 12, 1452, 1997, 1478
001110011011000010110100101100100001000000111011101101001011011000110110000101100001000000111011101101000011010
conft :0box: 12, 1485, 2010, 1525
010110001101101000001000000111011101100001011100110010000001101110011011110111010000100000011011010111100100100
conft :90.3502box: 12, 1532, 2002, 1558
```

A good output that can be converting back.

I would like the others to read better so I can then start on the other part of parsing and reading it to ascii. Any help or recommendations. I would like to do it in c++ if possible if I should try other library's I will.